# How to invert a value on Ruby

Tags: ruby, numeric

If you have a set of numbers in an array how can you invert them so that the positive ones are negative and the negative are then positive.

I've tried the below, but doesn't seem to work.

```
 def invert(list)
  list.each {|x| x * (-1)}
 end
```

Comment: Your code does indeed calculate the opposite of each value, but the result is neither displayed nor saved back into another array. You can see the resulting values with `list.each {|x| puts x * (-1)}`

Comment: change `each` to `map` and hey presto.

Answer (score 15):

So simple

```
[1, 5, 7, -3, -47, 0].map { |i| -i }
 => [-1, -5, -7, 3, 47, 0]
```

Even shorter.

```
[1, 5, 7, -3, -47, 0].map(&:-@)
 => [-1, -5, -7, 3, 47, 0]
```

It's the unary minus method

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` will return a new list, Using `map!` will modify list itself

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = list.map {|i| -i } 
# list still be [1, 2, 3]
# new list = [-1, -2, -3]
list.map! {|i| -i } 
# list changed to [-1, -2, -3]
```